# Errors while running the first statement in spark-shell

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I'm learning Apache Spark and I'm following Spark the definitive guide Big Data Processing made simple. The first statement that is written there to run is:

> val myRange = spark.range(1000).toDF("number")

Before running this statement first I started the spark-shell by running the command:

> spark-shell --master local[*]

After starting spark-shell everything was started correctly, but when I'm running the first query the following thing I got to my terminal (maybe I'm lagging just because of lack of knowledge or maybe I'm missing something that I need to know):

```
arctic-oak2:~ abhijeet$ spark-shell --master local[*]
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
18/02/26 12:21:09 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Spark context Web UI available at http://192.168.0.125:4040
Spark context available as 'sc' (master = local[*], app id = local-1519627870273).
Spark session available as 'spark'.
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.2.1
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.11.8 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_161)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.


scala> val myRange = spark.range(1000).toDF("number")
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder':
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$.org$apache$spark$sql$SparkSession$$instantiateSessionState(SparkSession.scala:1062)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$sessionState$2.apply(SparkSession.scala:137)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$sessionState$2.apply(SparkSession.scala:136)
  at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState$lzycompute(SparkSession.scala:136)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState(SparkSession.scala:133)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.<init>(Dataset.scala:171)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.range(SparkSession.scala:554)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.range(SparkSession.scala:527)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.range(SparkSession.scala:515)
  ... 48 elided
Caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileAlreadyExistsException: Parent path is not a directory: /tmp hive
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirMkdirOp.unprotectedMkdir(FSDirMkdirOp.java:231)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirMkdirOp.createSingleDirectory(FSDirMkdirOp.java:191)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirMkdirOp.createChildrenDirectories(FSDirMkdirOp.java:166)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirMkdirOp.mkdirs(FSDirMkdirOp.java:97)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.mkdirs(FSNamesystem.java:3896)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.mkdirs(NameNodeRpcServer.java:984)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.mkdirs(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:622)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:616)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:982)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2049)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2045)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2043)
;
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:106)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.databaseExists(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:194)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog$lzycompute(SharedState.scala:105)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog(SharedState.scala:93)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.externalCatalog(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:39)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.catalog$lzycompute(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:54)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.catalog(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:52)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.catalog(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:35)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.BaseSessionStateBuilder.build(BaseSessionStateBuilder.scala:289)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$.org$apache$spark$sql$SparkSession$$instantiateSessionState(SparkSession.scala:1059)
  ... 57 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileAlreadyExistsException: Parent path is not a directory: /tmp hive
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirMkdirOp.unprotectedMkdir(FSDirMkdirOp.java:231)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirMkdirOp.createSingleDirectory(FSDirMkdirOp.java:191)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirMkdirOp.createChildrenDirectories(FSDirMkdirOp.java:166)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirMkdirOp.mkdirs(FSDirMkdirOp.java:97)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.mkdirs(FSNamesystem.java:3896)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.mkdirs(NameNodeRpcServer.java:984)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.mkdirs(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:622)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:616)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:982)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2049)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2045)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2043)

  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:522)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.<init>(HiveClientImpl.scala:191)
  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader.createClient(IsolatedClientLoader.scala:264)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:362)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:266)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.client$lzycompute(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:66)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.client(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:65)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply$mcZ$sp(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:195)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:195)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:195)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:97)
  ... 66 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileAlreadyExistsException: Parent path is not a directory: /tmp hive
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirMkdirOp.unprotectedMkdir(FSDirMkdirOp.java:231)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirMkdirOp.createSingleDirectory(FSDirMkdirOp.java:191)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirMkdirOp.createChildrenDirectories(FSDirMkdirOp.java:166)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirMkdirOp.mkdirs(FSDirMkdirOp.java:97)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.mkdirs(FSNamesystem.java:3896)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.mkdirs(NameNodeRpcServer.java:984)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.mkdirs(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:622)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:616)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:982)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2049)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2045)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2043)

  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
  at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.instantiateException(RemoteException.java:106)
  at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.unwrapRemoteException(RemoteException.java:73)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.primitiveMkdir(DFSClient.java:3002)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.mkdirs(DFSClient.java:2970)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$21.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1047)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$21.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1043)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.mkdirsInternal(DistributedFileSystem.java:1061)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.mkdirs(DistributedFileSystem.java:1036)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Utilities.createDirsWithPermission(Utilities.java:3679)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.createRootHDFSDir(SessionState.java:597)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.createSessionDirs(SessionState.java:554)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:508)
  ... 80 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: Parent path is not a directory: /tmp hive
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirMkdirOp.unprotectedMkdir(FSDirMkdirOp.java:231)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirMkdirOp.createSingleDirectory(FSDirMkdirOp.java:191)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirMkdirOp.createChildrenDirectories(FSDirMkdirOp.java:166)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirMkdirOp.mkdirs(FSDirMkdirOp.java:97)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.mkdirs(FSNamesystem.java:3896)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.mkdirs(NameNodeRpcServer.java:984)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.mkdirs(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:622)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:616)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:982)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2049)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2045)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2043)

  at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1475)
  at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1412)
  at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:229)
  at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy23.mkdirs(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.mkdirs(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:558)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
  at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:191)
  at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
  at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy24.mkdirs(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.primitiveMkdir(DFSClient.java:3000)
  ... 90 more

scala>
```

I just want to know whether I've installed Spark properly or not or anything that I need to do before executing these statements?

Comment: how did you installed spark ?

Comment: I have downloaded spark binary files from spark official site then I setup the path for executing it's command

Comment: `Parent path is not a directory: /tmp hive` seems quite obvious? Do you have `/tmp hive` written in any of your config files? There shouldn't be a space in it.

Comment: there  are so many config files can you please be more specific that where I'm supposed to search for this

Answer (score 0):

This is an Hive error .

Hive uses the temporary directory both on hdfs and your local machine.

Its seems like Hive cannot on /tmp/ (on hdfs).

You can check on Hdfs , if /tmp exists as a directory and if you can write on it.

You can check hive.exec.scratchdir for more details.